# Understanding function returns and callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am having an issue with the order of my functions, and I'm unsure why.

When hovering over the call for `function_2` within the first function, VSCode gives me the result of `Promise<void>`, and the console outputs `undefined` when run (before `function_2()` even finishes).

Since I'm editing in VSCode, it tells me at the top when I hover over a `return` that it is for the `request` callback, so I have a general idea of what the issue is. Past that I have no idea, and it's most likely due to my lack of understanding about returns on promises and/or the true sequence of when things happen in a script.

Everything else in my code works without issue.

I have researched this quite extensively without luck (both on this site and in some general code documentation), but please let me know if there is something I missed.

I have included the general order of my functions below, and where the `return` calls are.

```js
async function_1() {
const check = await function_2();
return console.log(check);
}
```

```js
async function_2() {
...
    if(...){
    ...
        request(... => {
            ...
            while(...) {
                if(...) {
                ...
                return 'result'; //<<<RETURN
                }
                await  msg.channel.awaitMessages({
                ...
                }).then((c) => {
                    if() {
                    ...
                        if() {
                        ...
                        return 'result'; //<<<RETURN
                        };
                    } else if {
                    ...
                    return 'result'; //<<<RETURN
                    } else {
                    
                    };
                }).catch((c) => {
                ...
                return 'result'; //<<<RETURN
                });
            }; //<<<end 'while'
        }); //<<<end 'request'
    }; //<<<end 'if'
};
```

If my explanation was not clear, or more code is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Kind of hard to follow without real code.  It appears you're mixing plain asynchronous callbacks and promises which is generally a nightmare to program.  It is best to promisify any asynchronous operation that does not already uses promises and then use promise logic for all your control flow and return/error management.  In addition `while()` loops and asynchronous code are sometimes troublesome (depending upon what your `while` condition actually is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode is able to analyze your code and conclude that it always returns `Promise<void>` a void return is the same as undefined in this context.

First of all `Promise<T>` is always returned from an `async` function.

Secondly, in the call to `request(... => {` you're providing a *callback*, the return value of this *callback* is used by *request* and not *function_2*.

This means that your returns inside your callbacks never return any value for `function_2`.

If you want to return a value from the parent `function_2` you can resolve a custom `Promise` like this:

```js
function function_2() { // note: not async because we already return a Promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(() => {
      /* ... */
      resolve("some value"); // effectively returns a value to the Promise
      if (error) {
        reject(error); // throw an error
      }
      /* ... */
    });

  });
}

try {
  const value = await function_2();
  console.log(value); // "some value"
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you! I knew that the returns weren't returning any value to `function_2` but I couldn't figure out how to fix it. Your response made sense and worked right away